# How do I report the results of a pairwise comparison in writing? What results should I include?

Tags: r, reporting, p-value, pairwise, emmeans

Using Emmeans I have created a pairwise comparison of some habitats in a model. I want to report that there is a significant difference between human-modified and forest habitats in writing. What is the correct way to do this? I imagine something along the lines of (p<.0001, t.ratio= -14.580), but I'm not sure exactly which of the results in the table(s) below should be included, and if there is a certain order they should go in.

Part of the results of the Emmeans are below. Thank you!

```
$emmeans
 AVON_Habitat   emmean     SE   df lower.CL upper.CL
 Coastal        nonEst     NA   NA       NA       NA
 Forest           3.72 0.0336 9628     3.66     3.79
 Grassland        3.69 0.0242 9628     3.65     3.74
 Human Modified   4.10 0.0237 9628     4.05     4.15
 Marine           3.17 0.0574 9628     3.05     3.28
 Riverine         3.73 0.0292 9628     3.68     3.79
 Rock           nonEst     NA   NA       NA       NA
 Shrubland        3.61 0.0370 9628     3.54     3.68
 Wetland          3.44 0.0167 9628     3.40     3.47
 Woodland         3.78 0.0330 9628     3.71     3.84

Results are averaged over the levels of: title, Sedentary 
Results are given on the log10(mu + 1) (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

$contrasts
 contrast                   estimate      SE   df t.ratio p.value
 Forest - Grassland           0.0283 0.03683 9628   0.768  0.9990
 Forest - Human Modified     -0.3784 0.02595 9628 -14.580  <.0001
 Forest - Marine              0.5552 0.08303 9628   6.687  <.0001
 Forest - Riverine           -0.0118 0.01276 9628  -0.925  0.9957
 Forest - Rock                nonEst      NA   NA      NA      NA
 Forest - Shrubland           0.1133 0.02133 9628   5.312  <.0001
 Forest - Wetland             0.2848 0.04375 9628   6.509  <.0001
 Forest - Woodland           -0.0535 0.00923 9628  -5.801  <.0001
 Grassland - Human Modified  -0.4067 0.04185 9628  -9.718  <.0001
```

Comment: There is some flexibility, and may differ by field or journal. In APA style, you would report it as t(9628) = -14.58, p < .0001. (I can’t get markdown to cooperate, but t and p should be italicized.)

Comment: Interpretation questions should really be on CrossValidated not here. But my first question is what other factor(s) are involved? You have two marginal means that are non-estimable; that isn't routine at all. plus you apparently have interactions with those other factors. I think you are not yet anywhere near the question of how to report things  because there are other issues not even yet considered.